# How to count in recursive function?

Tags: python-3.x

The code below is quicksort in Python.
How do I count how many times comparison operates in the algorithm?

Although I assign `count = 0` at first, it is reset to 0 because of recursion.

```
def QuickSort(lst):
    if len(lst) > 1:
        pivot_idx = len(lst) // 2
        smaller_nums, larger_nums = [], []

        for idx, num in enumerate(lst):
            if idx != pivot_idx:
                if num < lst[pivot_idx]:
                    smaller_nums.append(num)

                else:
                    larger_nums.append(num)

        QuickSort(smaller_nums)
        QuickSort(larger_nums)
        lst[:] = smaller_nums + [lst[pivot_idx]] + larger_nums

    return lst
```

Comment: Where do you assign count?

Comment: right after def QuickSort(lst):

Comment: Except it's nowhere to be seen in the code that you've posted here...

Comment: At any rate, you can keep track of the count by adding a second parameter to your `QuickSort` function, although I'm not sure why you couldn't simply use `len(lst)` instead of `count`.

Comment: @WonKim In particular, which comparison do you want?

Comment: What exactly I want to count is how many times comparison occurs in this algorithm.

Comment: @WonKim This isn't really a part of the algorithm, so I'll assume you want to count the number of comparisons as an exercise or for performance reasons. First off, I'd set `pivot_idx` to `0`, because it's simpler. You could then get rid of the `if idx != pivot_idx` step. That being said, shouldn't you be able to calculate the number of comparisons, based on the size of the initial input?

Comment: @WonKim Would you mind amending the question to clarify whether you need to *count the comparisons one by one* or whether a simple calculation would do?

Comment: @SwifthsNamesake Oh, I'm sorry to have made confusion. I also assumed that there is a part of code to count. Just give me a second to make it clear.

Comment: Just to be clear, does that mean you no longer care about the `count`? If so, you should close or at least edit the answer to say so.

Comment: I think you have to check my answer bellow, I thought I didn't understand you, but I did, so I erased it thinking it was wrong. Consider taking a look, and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it recursively as parameter:

```
def QuickSort(lst, count=0):
    if len(lst) > 1:
        pivot_idx = len(lst) // 2
        smaller_nums, larger_nums = [], []

        for idx, num in enumerate(lst):
            if idx != pivot_idx:
                if num < lst[pivot_idx]:
                    smaller_nums.append(num)

                else:
                    larger_nums.append(num)

        count = QuickSort(smaller_nums, count+1)[1]
        count = QuickSort(larger_nums, count+1)[1]
        lst[:] = smaller_nums + [lst[pivot_idx]] + larger_nums


    return (lst,count)
```

Comment: I think you understood what I asked. It helps me a lot!! Thank you Jay!

Comment: @WonKim No problem! Please accept and upvote if this helped :)

Comment: Is upvote the upward arrow besides your code? I'm a newbie. How can I accept your help?

Comment: @WonKim This counts the number of recursive iterations, not the number of comparisons. But maybe that's what the OP wanted?

Answer (score 3):

> Edit, I was erased this answer because I thought it was incorrect, but I think it was correct after all

as suggested, I think also is better if the function is stateless:
You can return the lst and the number of calls:

```
def QuickSort(lst, ncalls=0):
  ncalls += 1

  if len(lst) > 1:
    pivot_idx = len(lst) // 2
    smaller_nums, larger_nums = [], []

    for idx, num in enumerate(lst):
        if idx != pivot_idx:
            if num < lst[pivot_idx]:
                smaller_nums.append(num)

            else:
                larger_nums.append(num)
    lst1, ncalls = QuickSort(smaller_nums, ncalls)
    lst1, ncalls = QuickSort(larger_nums, ncalls)
    lst[:] = smaller_nums + [lst[pivot_idx]] + larger_nums



  return lst,ncalls


QuickSort([1,3,52,4,6,5])
=> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 52],7
```

Answer (score -2):

Assign count as a global variable and set it to zero. That is, set `count=0` outside the definition of the function and increment it every time you compare.

Comment: That's a really bad idea.

Comment: Actually I've been trying not to use global variable.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake why is this a bad idea?

Comment: Global variable could occur confusions.

Comment: Using global variables is a great way of ending up with entangled and unreusable code. For instance, you'd have to reset the global variable manually every time you wanted to use the sorting function.